# Double line integral of $1/|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}|$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: vector-analysis

I was wondering how to express the closed-form solution of the following double line integral in $\mathbb{R}^n$:

$$
\int_{\mathbf{x}_1}^{\mathbf{x}_2}
\int_{\mathbf{y}_1}^{\mathbf{y}_2}
\frac{1}{|\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y}|} d\mathbf{x} d\mathbf{y}
$$

where

$$ \mathbf{x} = [x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n]^T $$
$$ \mathbf{y} = [y_1, y_2, \dots, y_n]^T $$
$$ |\mathbf{x}| = \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n|x_k|^2} $$
$$ |\mathbf{y}| = \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n|y_k|^2} $$

given that $\mathbf{x}_1, \mathbf{x}_2, \mathbf{y}_1, \mathbf{y}_2$ are all distinct from each other and the lines $\mathbf{x}_1, \mathbf{x}_2$ and $\mathbf{y}_1, \mathbf{y}_2$ do not cross each other. That is, it is granted that $|\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y}| > 0$ when evaluating the integral.

---

I thought on using coordinate translation to do the integration along the line $\mathbf{z}_1, \mathbf{z}_2$ in relation to the origin

$$
\int_{\mathbf{z}_1}^{\mathbf{z}_2}
\frac{1}{|\mathbf{z}|} d\mathbf{z}
=
\ln{\frac{
\sum_{k=1}^n \mathbf{z}_{2,k}(\mathbf{z}_{2,k} - \mathbf{z}_{1,k})
+ \sqrt{ (\sum_{k=1}^n \mathbf{z}_{2,k})
(\sum_{k=1}^n (\mathbf{z}_{2,k} - \mathbf{z}_{1,k})) }
}{
\sum_{k=1}^n \mathbf{z}_{1,k}(\mathbf{z}_{2,k} - \mathbf{z}_{1,k})
+ \sqrt{ (\sum_{k=1}^n \mathbf{z}_{1,k})
(\sum_{k=1}^n (\mathbf{z}_{2,k} - \mathbf{z}_{1,k})) }
}}
$$

where $\mathbf{z}_{1,k}$ is the $k$-th coordinate of the point $\mathbf{z}_{1}$.

But then I run out of ideias on how to proceed further and do the second integral taking advantage of that result...

Comment: I think that this integral can be interpreted as the electric potential energy between two negatively charged rods whose charges are evenly distributed along their length. If you don't get an answer here, try physics stack exchange - maybe someone has determined this integral experimentally for $n=3$.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a double line integral, you cam try making that explicit $\int_{x_{1}}^{x_{2}}dxF(x)=|x_{1}-x_{2}|\int_{0}^{1}dtF(x_{1}+t(x_{2}-x_{1}))$

thus

$\int_{x_{1}}^{x_{2}}\int_{y_{1}}^{y_{2}}dxdyF(|x-y|)=|x_{1}-x_{2}||y_{1}-y_{2}|\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}dsdtF(|x_{1}-y_{1}+t(x_{2}-x_{1})-s(y_{2}-y_{1})|)$

The interesting part of the integral becomes

$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}dsdtF(|x_{1}-y_{1}+t(x_{2}-x_{1})-s(y_{2}-y_{1})|)=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}dsdtF(\sqrt{A+Bt+Cs+Dts+Et^{2}+Fs^{2}})$

For the correct values of $A,B,C,D,E,F$
So you are left to solve

$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}dsdt {1\over\sqrt{A+Bt+Cs+Dts+Et^{2}+Fs^{2}}}$ which might be easier